# Need help matching IP subnet with ruby regex

Tags: ruby

I am trying to match first two octets of an IP to determine network subnet.
IP start with `10.43` or `10.44` or `10.46` but not `10.45`, tried to match with this expression `10.4{3|4|6}` but it matches only `10.44` and `10.46`

Any guess why not matching `10.43`

Comment: Wrong comment, deleted.

Comment: Your regex syntax is wrong. Try `/10\.4(3|4|6)/`

Comment: Indeed. Read too fast actually. Surprising it did even work in the first place.

Comment: Following expression helped me however any suggestions will be highly appreciated

Comment: /(^10.4[3-4|6]\b)/

Comment: If you're dealing with subnets, why not use an IP address gem which does all that for you? Especially if you're not very familiar with regex.

Answer (score 3):

While a regex will work (@Stefan has already provided one) and I have no idea about your implementation the [`IPAddr`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/IPAddr.html#method-i-mask-21) standard library may interest you e.g.

```
 acceptable_sub_nets = ["10.43.0.0","10.44.0.0","10.46.0.0"]
 my_list_of_ips.select do |ip|
   acceptable_sub_nets.include?(IPAddr.new(ip).mask(16).to_s)
 end
```

For example

```
IPAddr.new("10.43.22.19").mask(16).to_s
#=> "10.43.0.0"
IPAddr.new("192.168.0.1").mask(16).to_s
#=> "192.168.0.0"
```

Additionally you could do something like

```
 acceptable_sub_nets = ["10.43.0.0","10.44.0.0","10.46.0.0"].map do |subnet|
      IPAddr.new(subnet).mask(16).to_range
 end

 my_list_of_ips.select do |ip|
   acceptable_sub_nets.any? {|range| range.cover?(ip) } 
 end
```

Example

```
subnet_range = IPAddr.new("10.43.0.0").mask(16).to_range
subnet_range.cover?("10.43.22.19")
#=> true
subnet_range.cover?("192.168.0.1")
#=> false
```

**Update** (Thank you @JordanRunning)

The second option can be simplified to

```
acceptable_sub_nets = [
      #including the mask range
      IPAddr.new("10.43.0.0/16"),
      IPAddr.new("10.44.0.0/16"),
      IPAddr.new("10.46.0.0/16")]

 my_list_of_ips.select do |ip|
   acceptable_sub_nets.any? {|range| range.include?(ip) } 
 end
```

This does not require conversion to a `Range` but rather leverages `IPAddr#include?` directly.

Comment: Your second solution is definitely the right approach. However, you don't need `to_range`. IPAddr has an `include?`/`===` method: https://repl.it/JYpr

Comment: @JordanRunning thank you. Updated accordingly with accreditation. BTW I hate that they aliased this as `===` I don't feel that it adds anything syntactically and `include?` is much more expressive and intentional

Comment: Since `===` is used by `case` expressions as well as `slice_before`/`_after`, `grep` and other methods, I think it's essential.

Comment: @JordanRunning fair point. Although I do not think I would ever actually use it in written code it does have an implied necessity

Comment: `case ip; when IPAddr.new('10.43.0.0/16'), IPAddr.new('10.44.0.0/16') then ...` is quite convenient ...

Comment: @Stefan agreed (although I hate case statements) my point was I don't think I would ever write `===` over `include?` as it lacks readability in comparison